# Is it possible to mirror my mouse and/or keyboard input across multiple programs on the same monitor?

Tags: windows

I want to open a few browser windows on the same monitor and control each of them at the same time, doing the exact same thing as each other, based on the input from my one mouse/trackpad and one keyboard.

As a weird example, let's say I have a web game with two accounts, and each one is opened side-by-side on two separate browser windows . I want those two accounts following the exact movements. Is this possible? I have tried searching but couldn't find anything similar. The closest was a program that allowed you to mirror an input but on multiple monitors or to other computers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could do it with AutoHotKey. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363576/8672) for inspiration.

Comment: @harrymc thank you so much, I will have a look.